# What does E_n mean

Tags: neural-networks, expected-value, notation

I came across the following symbol in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.09953.pdf) paper:

[image]

I am a little bit confused by the symbol [image]. Does it simply mean population average?

Comment: It seems to refer to expected value of the empirical distribution, ie the sample mean.

Comment: @CloseToC is the symbol defined anywhere? I couldn't find the definition online though.

Comment: No, but if you look at p. 23 of the paper above the last paragraph they say that $\hat{\Pr}(T=t')$ is $E_n[1(t_i=t')]$ and call that the sample frequency. $F_n$ is often used to denote the cdf of the empirical distribution, and $E_n$ the expectation wrt that distribution